# Expand vector in terms of others

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, sympy

I want to solve the equation:

```
       v0 = a1*v1 + a2*v2 + a3*v3 + a4*v4 + a5*v5
```

where `v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5` are known column matrix (vectors) and `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5` are numbers that should be calculated. I want to know if there is a function in `numpy,sympy` or `scipy` to calculate the equation directly or how I can solve the equation.
Please give me a link or a written example.

Comment: This is actually a perfectly good question, it's just phrased poorly.  To the OP: What you're asking for is `numpy.linalg.solve`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation represents a system of equations, where each element of `v0` is expressed as a sum of the respective elements in the arrays `v1,v2,v3,v4,v5`.

This is a perfectly determined case, i.e. the number of unknowns `a1,a2,a3,s4,s5` equals the number of equations, which is the length of the vectors `v1,v2,v3,v4,v5`.

```
from numpy import allclose,zeros_like
from numpy.random import rand    
from numpy.linalg import solve

# generate the 5 vectors as random arrays
mat = rand(5,5)
v1,v2,v3,v4,v5 = mat.T
v0 = rand(5)
x= solve(mat,v0)

#first check
assert allclose(dot(mat,x),v0)

#2nd check, which is the equation of the OP
res = zeros_like(v0)
for xj,vj in zip([v1,v2,v3,v4,v5],x):
    res+= xj*vj

assert allclose(res,v0)
```

Comment: @user3109979, consider accepting this answer if it satisfies you, and possibly the other answers to your other questions.